# Run apk x86 in Emulator 2.0 Android Studio

Tags: android, apk, emulation

Hello I installed a Facebook apk android 2.0 emulator in a studio with an ABI armeabi-v7a works but is very slow and not the next. It is that if you use a x86 or x86-64 ABI the apk not load because it is not written for this type of processor, anyone can tell me if there apks that can be installed on x86 or x86-64 ABIS?

Answer (score 0):

They do not seem to provide a lot of x86 apk, but this is a relatively recent one: http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/facebook-2/facebook/facebook-75-0-0-0-51-release/

Comment: Thaks! run perfect!